# Pressing 'E' in Cygwin Bash starts infinite loop of 'Ex' characters

Tags: bash, shell, windows-8, cygwin

I am running Windows 8.1 and have been using Cygwin bash shell with "Out of Box" settings.  I recently upgraded to the 1.7.34 64 bit release and now have a problem when I run the shell.

Whenever I type the letter 'e' the shell immediately converts it to a repeating string of 'Ex' which continues until I type 'Ctrl+C'.  It makes using the shell impossible.  This only happens with the lowercase 'e' character, uppercase is fine.  I have no alias set up and can find nothing in my configurations that might cause this.  I tried wiping out my installation and installing cleanly but that did not resolve the issue.  I've researched on Google, StackOverflow, and the CygWin site but have found nothing to point me at a solution.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you run `read foo` then type `e` while `read` is waiting for input does this happen there too? Does it happen if you use `read -e foo` instead?

Comment: @Etan It might be difficult for him to type `read`.

Comment: @RossRidge You have a point. A script that doesn't use that in the name can be used instead though.

Comment: Do you have a .inputrc file, or any init scripts that use `bind`? If so, see [this previous question & its answers](http://superuser.com/questions/873546/bash-cant-type-e-or-ill-get-infinitely-repeating-hs) for an example of how that can cause problems like this.

Comment: @Etan - As Ross mentioned, I can't type "read".  I did create a shell script containing "read -e foo" and while that is running I can type 'e' w/o the issue.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - I do have .inputrc but neither that nor any other init scripts contain 'bind'.
I tried bind -p to see what is bound and found this to be interesting:
All the alphabetic characters seem to be "self-insert" EXCEPT "e".  For example:
"a": self-insert
"b": self-insert
"c": self-insert
"d": self-insert
"f": self-insert
"g": self-insert
I suspect the link you sent me should help me track this down as this does seem to be some sort of bind issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Davisson's link provided the answer.  I had an "echo" statement in .inputrc which caused a bad binding.  Once I removed that the problem was eliminated.  Thanks to all who commented and pointed me towards the solution.